# Enable SwipeRefreshLayout only when AppBarLayout expanded completely

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, android-appbarlayout

How can I enable `SwipeRefreshLayout` only when `AppBarLayout` expanded completely. I need to enable a refreshing mode only on the next swipe gesture. Now, I try so

```
appBar.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
  @Override
  public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, final int verticalOffset) {
    refreshLayout.setEnabled(verticalOffset == 0);
  }
});
```

Of course, it works! But it works not so like I need. This code enables a refreshing mode immediately while user continues the swipe gesture. I need to enable it only on the next swipe after the `AppBarLayout` expansion.

Who knows how to make it?

Comment: try to set offset to refresh layout

Comment: What for? Can u explain, pls?

Comment: As I understood you refresh layout appears in the same moment when app bar layout is for example in the middle of expanding. Why not to simple put offset with size of app bar layout so it will be start refreshing if you exceed this offset.

Comment: No, `SwipeRefreshLayout` enables a refreshing mode only when `AppBarLayout` already expanded. But user doesn't finish a swipe gesture to expand `AppBarLayout`. E.g. if device is tablet and user makes a swipe from top to bottom of screen then at first `AppBarLayout` will expanded and after refreshing mode will enabled. Although user just want expands `AppBarLayout` only.

Comment: I need to separate these processes in two swipe gestures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I was stumbling on the same problem. and here is what I've found. My solution isn't perfect, but it's working for me.
Let's suppose we have an AppBarLayout and RecyclerView wrapped in SwipeRefreshLayout.
Attention! Kotlin detected.

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener { _, motionEvent ->
        if (motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL
            || motionEvent.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            // 0.5f is used because I have snap parameter for CollapsingToolbar
            // and it automatically collapses/expands
            // if user finishes his scroll action in the middle of collapsing
            // so if AppBar is going to be completely expanded
            // we need to enable SwipeRefreshLayout
            swipeRefreshLayout.isEnabled =
                (appBarLayout.collapsingPercentage() < 0.5f)
        }
        false
    }

/**
 * @return 1.0f if AppBarLayout is completely collapsed,
 * 0.0f if completely expanded, percentage of
 * total height collapsed when collapsing/expanding is in progress.
 */
fun AppBarLayout.collapsingPercentage()
    = Math.abs(this.height - this.bottom) / this.totalScrollRange.toFloat()
```

Answer (score 0):

appbarLayout?.addOnOffsetChangedListener(AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { _, verticalOffset ->
swipeLayout?.isEnabled = verticalOffset == 0
})